# How can I add radiobuttons to a alert?

Tags: javascript, html

So I am making a game powered by only alerts, prompts, and variables. How can I put radiobuttons inside of prompts or an alert? Progress so far:

```
alert("Welcome to...\nGRANDMA SIMULATOR 2014!\nEnjoy your stay, sweetie pie. Make yourself at home.\nCopyright (c) CookieModding. All rights served.")
var age = prompt("How old are you?")
alert("Wow! You are " + age + " already? Just yesterday it feels like I was giving you your bottle. You grow up so fast. *gives hug*")
alert("Would you like some cookies?") //I need radiobuttons that say, "YES" or "NO"
```

Comment: almost 100% certain alerts can only contain strings. You could use window.confirm (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.confirm) to at least have a choice?

Comment: Thank you! I will use this for now, until I found a way I like to use radio buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible using `alert()`. It is a method of the window object which cannot interpret HTML tags. So whilst you could add HTML in the string it wouldn't render it as html.

You would need to use a modal/dialog box in JavaScript.

E.g.

- http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals
- http://jqueryui.com/dialog/